# Is there a contractible space with a free circle action?

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups, group-actions

Question in title. Seems no to me (some vague intuition here about contracting orbits to a fixed point), but I can't prove it. I'd prefer to be wrong.

(I'm curious because I am thinking about group quotients by non-free actions, so was thinking about the action of the circle on the complex numbers ... And this is because I am learning about algebraic stacks.)

Comment: For every group $G$, there is a thing called $EG$ which does the trick → https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space

Comment: @PseudoNeo Wikipedia says that $EG$ is *weakly* contractible: Is it also contractible?

Comment: For $S^1$, $EG$ is the infinite dimensional sphere.

Comment: Some constructions of $EG$ are CW-complexes. In this case, weakly contractible is really the same as contractible. I think that the point of this definition is that what people call $EG$ is really only well defined up to weak homotopy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the free action of $S^1$ on the odd sphere $S^{2n+1} = \{(z_0, \dots, z_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n:\ |z_0|^2 + \cdots + |z_n|^2 = 1\}$ by
$$e^{i\theta}.(z_0, \dots, z_n) = (e^{i\theta} z_0, \dots, e^{i\theta} z_n).$$
These actions extend across the direct limit $S^\infty = \bigcup S^{2n+1}$, which is contractible.

Comment: Note that this exactly the total space of the bundle $ES^1 \to BS^1$. Normally we just get a weakly-contractible space for $EG$; we're safely in the category of CW-complexes here, though, where Whitehead's theorem implies that weakly-contractible is equivalent to contractible.

Answer (score 1):

Just take $X$ to be the total space of the universal bundle $ES^1\rightarrow BS^1$ where $BS^1$ is the infinite dimensional complex projective space which is the classifying space of $S^1$.